# R data.table setting values

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to set the following data.tables px & vol using the following code. (falling back to a slow for loop)

```
a=data.table(
  date_id = rep(seq(as.Date('2013-01-01'),as.Date('2013-04-10'),'days'),5),
  px =rnorm(500,mean=50,sd=5),
  vol=rnorm(500,mean=500000,sd=150000),
  id=rep(letters[1:5],each=100)
  )

b=data.table(
  date_id=rep(seq(as.Date('2013-01-01'),length.out=600,by='days'),5),
  id=rep(letters[1:5],each=600),
  px=NA_real_,
  vol=NA_real_
  )

setkeyv(a,c('date_id','id'))
setkeyv(b,c('date_id','id'))
```

and the following approach doesn't work.

```
s = a[1,id]
d = a[1,date_id]
b[id == s & date_id == d, list(names(b)[3:4])] <- a[id == s & date_id ==d, list(names(a)[2:3])]
```

It fails with the following code

```
Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, id == s & date_id == d, list(names(b)[3:4]),  : 
  j must be atomic vector, see ?is.atomic
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I set those values from one data.table to the other elementwise. The actual table has quite a few columns so writing them out by hand is not an option for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your example.

First , if you want to access columns in a data.table in the form `dt[ , "col" ]` you have to add `with=FALSE`:

```
b[ , names(b)[3:4], with = FALSE ]
```

Second, I am not sure if assigning values in a data.table is possible at all using the assignment operator (`<-`). For this purpose there is the ultra fast *update-by-reference* operator:

```
b[
  id == s & date_id == d,
  names(b)[3:4] := a[id == s & date_id ==d, names(a)[2:3], with = FALSE],
  with = FALSE
]
```

Third, subsetting data.tables by `dt[ col == value, ]` syntax is possible but slow. Especially if you have already keys set on the columns you want to subset by, you should use the following syntax:

```
b[
  J(d,s),
  names(b)[3:4] := a[J(d,s), names(a)[2:3], with = FALSE] ,
  with = FALSE
]
```

Fourth, this all looks to me as if you want a simple join of two tables. So the most straight forward would be

```
a[ b[ , list(date_id, id) ] ]
```

Or considering your comment, that you only want to overwrite the columns `px`and `vol` in the subset by `a`:

```
b[a, c("px", "vol") := a[, list(px, vol)], with = FALSE ]
```

Comment: Excellent answer thank you @Beasterfield. I don't want a simple join because I'm trying to replace the values in b with those in a. I've tried that in an earlier example but will have another go in case I got it wrong. Appreciate the helpful and extremely clear response.

Comment: Actually, I take that back your option 4 worked perfectly. Is it overwriting all the existing values in b? I need to preserve the non a values. Thanks again